# select image from computer in ionic app to serve it to server

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework, blob

My ionic app is sometimes used in browser and I need to upload some images. 
I have implemented a code to select my file, then I have a `formData` type where I put my image in. 
I am trying to upload my file to the server using a post request but I am not sur how to do it.

When I receive my file in my php code, I INSERT it inside my db, I got a blob file in my db but I think it's not the image, it's way to small...

html file :

```
  <input
  style="display: none"
  type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"
  #fileInput>
<button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
<button (click)="onUpload()">Upload!</button>
```

ts file :

```
onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    console.log(this.selectedFile);
  }

  onUpload() {
    // upload code goes here
      // this.http is the injected HttpClient
  let uploadData = new FormData();
  uploadData.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
  console.log(this.selectedFile);
   this.http.post(this.server + 'saveExo.php', this.selectedFile)
     .subscribe(resData => {
         console.log(resData);
     });
  }
```

php file :

```
<?php


header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

include "db.php";

$postjson = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$today = date('Y-m-d');

if ( isset( $_POST) ) {
    $result = json_encode(array('receive' => 'ok'));
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO EXO SET 
    image = '$_POST'");


    echo $result;
} else {
    $result = json_encode(array('receive' => 'nothing'));
    echo $result;
}

?>
```

Here is what I get inside my db : 
[image]

Thank you for your help, I think it's the wrong way to save my image in my db...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution is to convert your image to base64 in client-side using: [base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/) then store it on the server. to view it again, send the base64 to the client and convert again using base64 plugin.